# Changing ImageButton Image

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have set the `Image` for my `ImageButton` in `XML` but trying to change the image in the code below does nothing. Any ideas why?

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton myImageButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_farm_main);

    myImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
    myImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
    myImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want change the image not background.

Substitute

```
myImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

with

```
myImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

This code below works perfectly fine if you have a imagebutton in your layout file and a drawable name ic_launcher in drawable directory.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    ImageButton myImageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        myImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment below if that's not what you want.

Comment: Tried it. Same problem.

Comment: As suggested by @Naveen Kumar, you should check if the image is present in drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

You just make sure your image is available in all drawable folder you will create a common drawable folder in your res and then paste your image at that folder then you will try his concept and or otherwise you will try like this..**You just Set the image source it will give the answer**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageButton imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the image is present in your drawable folder or will you can  post your XML file

Comment: I double checked and the image is present in drawable folder.